# Update date field in one table, if found in other table with same date

Tags: sql, oracle

. I am using this query, but it wont work. Any thoughts or suggestion as to what is wrong here;

```
'UPDATE SAMPLE C SET SAMPLE.C_DATE = TO_DATE('01/01/2013','MM/DD/YYYY') and TO_DATE('12/31/2013','MM/DD/YYYY') WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MEMBER_A A, S_NEW B WHERE A.MEM_NBR = B.MEM_NBR AND B.M_ID IN (1111,2222,3333) AND A.L_TEST = TO_DATE('01/01/2013','MM/DD/YYYY') and TO_DATE('12/31/2013','MM/DD/YYYY') AND B.ID = C.ID)
```

I am not able to update it, and i am getting an error.

Any thoughts on how to make this better.
Thanks,

Comment: 1) Please format your SQL.  2) What DMBS is this for?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"

Comment: The parts marked by Patrick are simply wrong SQL syntax. You cannot set a date to (a date and a date). What do you expect should be the value?

Answer (score 0):

You have a fundamental problem.  What date do you want to set the value to?  I am guessing the first one.

There are a few other syntax issues.  The following may be what you want:

```
UPDATE SAMPLE
    SET C_DATE = TO_DATE('01/01/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM MEMBER_A A JOIN
                       S_NEW B
                       ON A.MEM_NBR = B.MEM_NBR AND
                  WHERE B.M_ID IN (1111,2222,3333) AND
                        A.L_TEST BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/01/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY') and TO_DATE('12/31/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND
                        B.ID = SAMPLE.ID
                 );
```

EDIT:

In Oracle, you can do the super-elegant two-subquery solution:

```
UPDATE SAMPLE
    SET C_DATE = (SELECT max(A.L_TEST)
                  FROM MEMBER_A A JOIN
                       S_NEW B
                       ON A.MEM_NBR = B.MEM_NBR AND
                  WHERE B.M_ID IN (1111,2222,3333) AND
                        A.L_TEST BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/01/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY') and TO_DATE('12/31/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND
                        B.ID = SAMPLE.ID
                 )
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM MEMBER_A A JOIN
                       S_NEW B
                       ON A.MEM_NBR = B.MEM_NBR AND
                  WHERE B.M_ID IN (1111,2222,3333) AND
                        A.L_TEST BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/01/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY') and TO_DATE('12/31/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND
                        B.ID = SAMPLE.ID
                 );
```

The `max()` is just to be sure that only one value is returned.

Comment: The A.L_TEST is a date field, but it does not have any data in it. I want to update the C_DATE field which is NULL (at this point of time), with the A.L_TEST data (i.e. date).

Comment: If `A.L_TEST` has no data, then just set `c_date` to `NULL`.

Comment: Makes sense to me now. But what if A.L_TEST has data tomorrow. Because, this is Health related claims data, and this A.L_TEST might come up with some dates. Who knows. As of now we don't have data in it. I Used 'SET C_DATE = A.L_TEST WHERE EXISTS'. But i get an error 'SQL Error: ORA-00904: "A"."L_TEST": invalid identifier'. Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing your c_date with two dates. That does not work this way. The code between ** need you attention. From your question is not clear what to do with it.

```
UPDATE SAMPLE C
SET SAMPLE.C_DATE = **TO_DATE('01/01/2013','MM/DD/YYYY') and TO_DATE('12/31/2013','MM/DD/YYYY')**
WHERE EXISTS
( SELECT *
  FROM   MEMBER_A A
  ,      S_NEW B
  WHERE  A.MEM_NBR = B.MEM_NBR
  AND    B.M_ID IN (1111,2222,3333)
  AND    A.L_TEST = **TO_DATE('01/01/2013','MM/DD/YYYY') and TO_DATE('12/31/2013','MM/DD/YYYY')**
  AND B.ID = C.ID
)
```

Comment: After getting some guidance, there is bit changes in the logic. We need to update the date in SAMPLE.C_DATE, if it is Null and A.L_TEST is NOT NULL. UPDATE SAMPLE SET SAMPLE.C_DATE = A.L_TEST WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MEMBER_A A JOIN S_NEW B ON A.MEM_NBR = B.MEM_NBR AND WHERE B.M_ID IN (1111,2222,3333) AND A.L_TEST BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/01/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY') and TO_DATE('12/31/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND B.ID = SAMPLE.ID ); Here's the code that i changed. But i am getting an error after executing it SQL Error: ORA-00904: "A"."L_TEST": invalid identifier.

Any suggestions.